# Security Exception - mscorlib, Retrieving COM class component with CLSID failed

Tags: web-services, security, exception, mscorlib

I have having trouble in this phase where it initialize the app.

```
public static void Initialise()
    {
        Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException); //throwing exception here
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    }
```

I have web config where

```
<trust level="full"/>
```

Message is:

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

Stack trace is as follows:

```
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.add_ThreadException(ThreadExceptionEventHandler value)
at Chronos.Shared.ErrorHandler.Initialise()
at Chronos.TeamLeader.Program.Main()
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Let me know if anyone need more info about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling a lot on passing this *security exception*. Read loads of blogs, involved in discussions but nothing worked out.

Finally found '**Enable ClickOnce Security Settings**' in msdn. I just followed those steps and disabled the Security Setting in Project properties.

Here is a link hope this helps some: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sfbfyk0.aspx

Comment: I had this problem when I switched from a 32 bit development machine to a 64 (not 100% sure that is related, but it is what I was doing).  The program ran when outside of Visual Studio, but would not run from within Visual Studio until I disabled the ClickOnce security.  Thanks a bunch, this was driving me crazy.

Comment: Just want to add that in my case it was a WinForm application, not a web app.

Comment: Thanks a million! This took me sooo long to find.. In my case it was winforms application too